# What is a good way to cast and call variable argument functions from a map dynamically at runtime WITHOUT using an external library

Tags: c++

Let's say I multiple functions with variable arguments:

```cpp
void greetWorld() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}

void greetName(const string& name) {
    cout << "Hello " << name << "!" << endl;
}

void printAddition(const int lhs, const int rhs) {
    cout << "Addition: " << to_string(lhs + rhs) << endl;
}
```

And these are stored in a map of `std::strings` to functions (functions being stored as a polymorphic class).

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
class DerivedFunction;

class BaseFunction {
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    void operator()(Args... args) const {
        (*static_cast<const DerivedFunction<Args...>*>(this))(args...);
    }
};

template<typename... Args>
class DerivedFunction : public BaseFunction {
public:
    DerivedFunction(void(*function)(Args...)) {
        this->function = function;
    }
    void operator()(Args... args) const {
        function(args...);
    }
private:
    void(*function)(Args...);
};

template<typename... Args>
unique_ptr<DerivedFunction<Args...>> make_function(
    void(*function)(Args...)
) {
    return std::make_unique<DerivedFunction<Args...>>(function);
}

int main() {
    unordered_map<string, unique_ptr<BaseFunction>> function_map;
    function_map.insert({ "greetWorld",    make_function(&greetWorld)    });
    function_map.insert({ "greetName",     make_function(&greetName)     });
    function_map.insert({ "printAddition", make_function(&printAddition) });

    ...
}
```

I can call the functions at compile time like:

```cpp
int main() {
    ...

    (*function_map.at("greetWorld"))();
    (*function_map.at("greetName"))("Foo"s);
    (*function_map.at("printAddition"))(1, 2);
}
```

If I then have a string, or stream like:

```
greetWorld
greetName     string Foo
printAddition int    1   int 2
```

What would be a good way to call the functions?
I can not figure out any way to cast a type at runtime.

---

### Why?

I am trying to implement some kind of remote call procedure for learning purposes. I do not want to use an external library as I am trying to learn how to implement this with the C++ standard library for the sake of understanding C++ more.

---

### What have I tried?

Not much. I've tested creating functions that take a `std::vector` of `std::any`s as an argument, and then had the function `any_cast` them to the type they are. Whilst this does work, it does not look nice, it requires duplicates of all functions, I would rather be able to write functions with meaningful arguments than ambigious.

---

### Minimum Example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

void greetWorld() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}

void greetName(const string& name) {
    cout << "Hello " << name << "!" << endl;
}

void printAddition(const int lhs, const int rhs) {
    cout << "Addition: " << to_string(lhs + rhs) << endl;
}

template<typename... Args>
class DerivedFunction;

class BaseFunction {
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    void operator()(Args... args) const {
        (*static_cast<const DerivedFunction<Args...>*>(this))(args...);
    }
};

template<typename... Args>
class DerivedFunction : public BaseFunction {
public:
    DerivedFunction(void(*function)(Args...)) {
        this->function = function;
    }
    void operator()(Args... args) const {
        function(args...);
    }
private:
    void(*function)(Args...);
};

template<typename... Args>
unique_ptr<DerivedFunction<Args...>> make_function(
    void(*function)(Args...)
) {
    return std::make_unique<DerivedFunction<Args...>>(function);
}

int main() {
    unordered_map<string, unique_ptr<BaseFunction>> function_map;
    function_map.insert({ "greetWorld",    make_function(&greetWorld)    });
    function_map.insert({ "greetName",     make_function(&greetName)     });
    function_map.insert({ "printAddition", make_function(&printAddition) });

    cout << "Calling functions at compile time." << endl << endl;

    (*function_map.at("greetWorld"))();
    (*function_map.at("greetName"))("Foo"s);
    (*function_map.at("printAddition"))(1, 2);

    //cout << endl << "Calling functions at runtime." << endl << endl;
    //string runtime =
    //  "greetWorld\n"
    //  "greetName     string Foo\n"
    //  "printAddition int    1   int 2";
    //
    // todo: call functions
}
```

---

---

---

### **Solved.**

If you apply the accepted solution, you can call functions from the text like I had wanted.
Here is new code for an example Tcp server and client. The client sends function names and arguments as a string to the server. The server then executes these. Exactly what I wanted.

```cpp
struct FunctionNameAndArguments {
    string function_name;
    vector<RPC> arguments;
};

FunctionNameAndArguments parseFunctionNameAndArguments(
    const string& function_name_and_arguments_string
) {
    istringstream ss(function_name_and_arguments_string);
    FunctionNameAndArguments function_name_and_arguments;
    // function name
    ss >> function_name_and_arguments.function_name;
    // arguments
    auto& arguments = function_name_and_arguments.arguments;
    while (!ss.eof()) {
        string function_type;
        ss >> function_type;
        // integer
        if (function_type == "int") {
            int value;
            ss >> value;
            arguments.push_back(value);
        }
        // string
        else if (function_type == "string") {
            string value;
            ss >> value;
            arguments.push_back(value);
        }
        else {
            throw exception("unknown argument type");
        }
    }
    return function_name_and_arguments;
}

int main() {
    unordered_map<string, RPCHandler> functions = {
        { "greetWorld", make_invoker(&greetWorld) },
        { "greetName", make_invoker(&greetName) },
        { "printAddition", make_invoker(&printAddition) }
    };

    char server;
    cout << "Server? (y/n): " << endl;
    cin >> server;
    // server
    if (server == 'y') {
        // accept client
        TcpListener listen;
        listen.listen(25565);
        TcpSocket client;
        listen.accept(client);

        size_t received;
        // receive size of string
        size_t size;
        client.receive(&size, sizeof(size), received);
        // receive function name and arguments as string
        string function_name_and_arguments_string;
        function_name_and_arguments_string.resize(size);
        client.receive(
            function_name_and_arguments_string.data(),
            size,
            received
        );
        // go through each line
        istringstream lines(function_name_and_arguments_string);
        string line;
        while (getline(lines, line)) {
            // parse function name and arguments
            auto [function_name, arguments] = parseFunctionNameAndArguments(
                line
            );
            // call function
            functions.at(function_name)(
                arguments
            );
        }
        
    }
    // client
    else {
        // connect to server
        TcpSocket server;
        server.connect("localhost", 25565);

        // function calls string
        const string function_calls =
            "greetWorld\n"
            "greetName     string Foo\n"
            "printAddition int    1   int 2";
        size_t size = function_calls.size();
        // send size of string
        server.send(&size, sizeof(size));
        // send function calls string
        server.send(function_calls.data(), size);
    }
}
```

Comment: `any way to cast a type at runtime` so, like, just `reinterpret_cast`? Sorry, C++ doesn't have [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)). If you want it, you have to implement it yourself.

Comment: _remote call procedure_ - for that you need to store your functions along with its arguments. Store lambda with captures into `std::function<void()>`. Your remote executor invokes those `std::function<void()>`.

Comment: @KamilCuk, that seems to involve a lot of changing to the functions, whereas libraries like `rpclib` can do that without changing the function at all (`srv.bind("printAddition", &printAddition);` is all I need to do to bind it, and `client.call("printAddition", 1, 2);` is all I need to do to call it). I realise that library is open source so I can see how they do it but it is too complicated looking for me to understand

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I'll give what you said a try

Comment: You map the runtime string to types by having a lookup table. This means you can only support a fixed set of types.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin that seems to work if I know what possible arguments could be passed when creating the map, or by making more complicated lamdba functions for stuff like user input, it's not entirely what I am looking for, it's a shame I can't seem to send the lamdba functions over a socket.

Comment: @PasserBy a fixed amount of types sounds good. I can create a map of `std::string` to `std::type_info`, I'm going to see what I can come up with that

Comment: `std::type_info` is useless in this case. You want a table of function pointers, which you cast to the correct type when you call them. Something like `std::unordered_map<std::string, void(*)()>`.

Comment: @PasserBy I am now lost on what these functions are meant to be doing, returning a type? It seems what I am wanting to do is way out of my league.

Comment: You know, after a short attempt at writing this, I'm not very convinced this is easily solvable in C++.

Comment: @PasserBy that's alright, I appreciated the help anyways, I'll just leave the hard stuff to external libraries for now and learn something easier elsewhere

Comment: @ColonD You cannot send a function over socket either. Making remote calls is essentially serializing/deserializing function arguments. The function itself must be available in the remote process: be compiled ahead-of-time or just-in-time before a call.

Comment: @passerby can you check my solution? Maybe it shows a way out for yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume you have a list of types (taking int and string as an example) usable in RPC, we can combine them in a `RPC` type and associated `RPCHandler` as follows:

```
using RPC = std::variant<int, std::string>;
using RPCHandler = std::function<void(std::vector<RPC>)>;
```

You want to create a `std::map<std::string, RPCHandler> dispatch` so you can do (given a `std::vector<RPC> args`):

```
dispatch[command](args);
```

This map can be constructed as follows:

```
void test0();
void test2(int, std::string);

std::map<std::string, RPCHandler> dispatch = {
  { "test0", make_invoker(test0) },
  { "test2", make_invoker(test2) },
};
```

where `make_invoker` returns a lambda of the correct shape.
The body of this lambda passes the function pointer, argument vector, and a `std::index_sequence` to `invoke_rpc`:

```
template<class... Arg>
RPCHandler make_invoker(void (*f)(Arg...)) {
   return [f](std::vector<RPC> args) {
      invoke_rpc(f, args, std::index_sequence_for <Arg...>{});
   };
}
```

Finally, `invoke_rpc` uses `std::get` on each argument in turn to convert it into the expected type. It does this by expanding the two given template parameter packs in parallel. Intuitively, this expands to `f(std::get<Arg0>(args.at(0), std::get<Arg1>(args.at(1))` with as many arguments to `f` as it expects (since the index sequence has the same length `Args...`).

```
template<class... Arg, std::size_t... I>
void invoke_rpc(void (*f)(Arg...), std::vector<RPC> args, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    f(std::get<Arg>(args.at(I))...);
}
```

If the vector is too short you get a `std::out_of_range` error, if there is an argument mismatch you get a `std::bad_variant_access`. You can improve error handling by checking the size of `args` before calling `f`, and using `std::holds_alternative` to see if all passed values match their proscribed type.

Comment: Awesome!

This works with all my example functions (although `greetName`'s argument had to be changed from `const string& name` to `const string name`).

It's very clean syntax wise and visually as well.

Comment: It uses a few features I currently do not know, I will need to research them.

From the top down:

I have never heard of `std::index_sequence` nor `std::index_sequence_for`.

I have never seen two parameter packs in one templated function before. I only learned about parameter packs a few weeks ago. I did not think it would work with two parameter packs (because how does it know when one ends and another begins?). Nor did I know parameter packs could use a specific type (like `std::size_t`). I have also never seen an `...` not directly next to the templated parameter: `(args.at(I))...`.

Comment: Do you have any specific resources you can recommend to learn about features like this?

I find `cppreference` very verbose and hard to understand, but that's because I am easily overwhelmed.

Comment: I believe you can use `std::remove_cv` and `std::remove_reference` together in the template parameter to `std::get` so that const-ness or reference-ness of function arguments does not clash with your variant.

Comment: As for resources, I vaguely remember reading [this](https://arne-mertz.de/2016/11/modern-c-features-variadic-templates/) and putting it together with the cppreference pages for template parameter pack expansion.

Comment: `f(EXPR...)` expands `EXPR` for the template parameter packs referenced and turns them into arguments to `f`. Presumably you can do it [without the index_sequence](https://medium.com/@matt.aubury/rip-index-sequence-2014-2017-9cc854aaad0), but this form is close to how I implemented it three years ago.

Comment: Well, thank you for the solution. It does exactly what I was looking for.